# Exercise for equivalence of the Prime Number Theorem (P.N.T)

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to recheck my proof of the exercise that the Prime Number Theorem is equivalent to $$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{\log p}{p}=\log x+M'+o(1).$$

The P.N.T here I mean the simplest form
$$\pi(x):=\sum_{p\le x}1=\dfrac{x}{\log x}+o\left(\dfrac{x}{\log x}\right).$$

I assumed first that the P.N.T is equivalent to
$$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{1}{p}=\log\log x+M+o\left(\dfrac{1}{\log x}\right),$$
then I use both this result and the P.N.T to try to prove the topmost exercise. It seems to me that the direction of assuming $\sum_{p\le x}\log p/p$ above to show the sum $\sum_{p\le x} 1/p$ is easier, so I would like to ask here the other direction.

Here are what I tried, I think the late arguments should be strengthen but I don't know how effectively can I do.

---

By the fact that $\pi(x)\sim\dfrac{x}{\log x}$ we have equivalently (and this is where I need to prove later)
$$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{1}{p}=\log\log x+M+o\left(\dfrac{1}{\log x}\right).$$

Let $$R(x):=\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{\log p}{p}-\log x=O(1),$$
where the last inequality is true from Merten's first theorem (which is proven by the use of $\log (n!)$ in the book so may not be serious here), here I want $R(x)=M'+o(1)$ for a constant $M'$.

We have further that
$$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{1}{p}=\int_{2^-}^x \dfrac{1}{\log t}d\left\{\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{\log p}{p}\right\}=\int_2^x\dfrac{dt}{t\log t}+\int_{2^-}^x \dfrac{dR(t)}{\log t}$$
$$\log\log x+M+o(1/\log x)=\log\log x-\log\log 2+\dfrac{R(x)}{\log x}+1-\int_{2}^x \dfrac{R(t)}{t\log^2 t} dt.$$

We thus have accidentally
$$M=1-\log_2 2+\int_{2}^{\infty}\dfrac{R(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt.$$

Moreover,
$$
\left|\dfrac{R(x)}{\log x}-\int_x^\infty \dfrac{R(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt\right|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{\log x},
$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $x>x_\epsilon$. Which is equivalent to
$$
\left|R(x)-\log x\int_x^\infty \dfrac{R(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt\right|<\epsilon.
$$

Denote $R:=\sup_{t\ge 1} R(t)$. We obtain
$$
\left|\log x\int_x^\infty \dfrac{R(t)}{t\log^2 t} dt\right| \le R.
$$
Therefore, by triangle inequality,
$$
\epsilon>\left|R(x)-\log x\int_x^\infty \dfrac{R(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt\right|\ge ||R(x)|-R|,
$$
so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |R(x)|=R$.

For consecutive primes $P,P'$ where $P<P'$, if $$R(P)=\sum_{p\le P}\dfrac{\log p}{p}-\log P<0,$$
then we have
$$R(P')=R(P)+\dfrac{\log P'}{P'}-\log\left(\dfrac{P'}{P}\right):= R(P)+\vartheta(P,P'),$$

We will prove that for large primes $P,P'$, $\vartheta(P,P')=o(1).$ The first term is obvious, the second we have $p_n\sim n\log n$ by the P.N.T so if $P=p_n, P'=p_{n+1}$,
$$\dfrac{P'}{P}<\dfrac{(1+\epsilon_1)}{(1-\epsilon_2)}\cdot\dfrac{n+1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}<1+\epsilon,$$
for all $n> n_{\epsilon}$. Hence, $\log(P'/P)=o(1)$

Consequently, as we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|R(x)|=R$, so $|R(x)|>R-\epsilon$ for large $x$, it is imposible for $R(x)$ to change the sign to positive as we add only small $o(1)$ changes so $R(x)$ will remain negative, and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}R(x)=-R$. For if $R(P)\ge 0$, we will have the same conclusion so that for some constant $M'$, $R(x)=M'+o(1)$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Don’t use $\log_2 x$ for $\log\log x.$ $\log_2 x$ already has a well-established meaning. Most number theory books I’ve seen just write $\log\log x.$